# performing comparisons with big.matrix (from the bigmemory package in R)

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I'd like to perform comparisons with a big.matrix.  here is some sample code below:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- matrix(rnorm(16), ncol=4)

# following line returns a logical matrix
x < 0

y <- as.big.matrix(x)

#I'd like a logical big matrix, or a big matrix of 0's & 1's
#but this line returns an error
y < 0

#this works, but I think it loads the big matrix into ram, which I don't want
#also returns a warning
as.big.matrix(y[,] < 0)[,]
```

Comment: An intermediate solution would be to do this per block. So that you can use base R code, but only on a small portion of the data that you access in RAM. I have developed big_apply() for this purpose (tuto here; https://privefl.github.io/bigstatsr/articles/big-apply.html).